# DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated

Tags: mongoose, deprecation-warning, punycode, userland

[vs code terminal showing deprecation warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RasHc.png)
(node:22063) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)

This is the issue.
my OS was ubuntu 22.04.
The problem cames when i am trying to use my database with mongoose.
The punycode can see somewhere in my package-lock.json file. I didn't use it myself , it's coming with node.

My node version is v21.0.0 , i downgraded it into v20.9.0 then v18.18.0 still the warning is there.
I installed userland module but nothing happens.

The problem i understand was the punycode is deprecated and need to use userland alternative punycode.js . But i didn't know how to make it possible.

Comment: Getting the same issue with macOS as well. Can we add a ubuntu tag and macOS tag as well? I am getting it while running a react native project

Comment: Same problem here with macOS. It happened when I npm installed mongoose.

Answer (score 2):

had the same problem,
i looked for punycode and found it in package-lock.json
the reason was i was using new version of Node.js v21.5.0,
which explains the deprecation warning for punycode.
i updated uri-js and that solved the problem
npm install uri-js@4.2.2

solved the problem

Comment: Did you run `npm install uri-js@4.2.2` globally, or is this per project?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved this Deprecation Warning:

Here’s a workaround that might help:

1. Go to your **node_modules** directory.
2. Find the **tr46** directory.
3. Open the **index.js** file in the **tr46** directory.
4. Replace current require line with this line:

   const punycode = require('punycode/');

But if you re-install npm packages, or update them, this correction will be lost. However, the Warning disappeared.

PS:
Just in case, I use **node v21.5.0**

Comment: Avoid editing files in `node_modules`

Comment: look in the package-lock.json what modules use it

Comment: In this particular case, patching a package in `node_modules` **may be** warranted, especially if the target package is a dependency of some other packages. To persist the fix, try to use [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package).

Answer (score 0):

this problem happen because punycode is deprecated in node version 21 and above...
downgrade to node version 20

Answer (score 0):

Punycode is deprecated in node version 21
Solution:NVM install and use node version 20.5.1

```
nvm install 20.5.1
nvm use 20.5.1
```